# Android - Multi Columns ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an `ArrayList<myObject>` and a `ListView` with a personal `ArrayAdapter<myObject>` using an inflated View that generates a list of `Button`s.

It works, but one button per line is quite layout consuming ^^

I wanted to know if it was possible to display two or more items (Button) per line and how to do such a thing ?

I thought about dividing my items in two lists (even and odd) but they'll have to scroll all-together for a better user experience...

any idea ? or object that already implements it ?

Thanks

Comment: can you please post your code for listview's row.xml.

Comment: it's no use here ?! in fact for the moment it's rather simple : linear layout containing a button where I set its text...

Comment: Then just add two buttons in Linearlayout having horizontal orientation.

Comment: @Darkendorf are you looking for something like this http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-tutorial-custom-adapter-for.html...

Comment: not at all, but thanks for this ref !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that case, just take a GridView with 2 columns, i am sure this will fulfill your requirement.

**gridview_row.xml**

```
    <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

and take GridView instad of ListView as:

```
 <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/gridview01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp">

 </GridView>
```

Once you are done with these 2 things, then **implement the code in your custom adapter**. And i am sure your current adapter is also 90% useful, you just need to change the code according the row xml file.

Comment: sorry my adapter is tricky, i'll accept your answer as soon as i valid it ^^ inside eclipse, it seems to be exactly what i need !

Comment: +1 @Darkendorf its not going to be a tricky anyhow, as you are having ArrayList of objects you can define an adapter once and use the same adapter(after little changes) in future. I am doing this practice since i learnt android.

Comment: i know thanks, but it's my Simple xml's serialization of an xml that was tricky ^^ and now it works like a charm !!